# What is the purpose of using `@display` annotation in Ballerina?

Tags: annotations, ballerina

In Ballerina, I've come across code that uses the `@display` annotation in service and record parameters. Can someone please clarify what the `@display` annotation is used for and provide some use cases for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@display` annotation in Ballerina is a general purpose annotation that serves various use cases.

One use case is that when multiple services interact within a project, applying the same `id` in the `@display` annotation ensures the link of services with the clients accurately. This is useful to visualize the connection between clients and services in the diagrams. For more in-depth information, you can refer to [this](https://wso2.com/ballerina/vscode/docs/design-the-application/explore-the-architecture-view/#service-identifiers).

Additionally, the `label` attribute of the `@display` annotation allows you to assign labels to services or records in diagrams. This feature enables you to provide meaningful names for services or records, enhancing their comprehensibility for developers.

These are just a few of the use cases, but developers can adapt the `@display` annotation for various other purposes based on their preferences.